# How can I pass inputs from my C program to another program running in the command line?

Tags: c++, windows, api, cmd

I want to provide inputs to a program (not written by me) running in command line through a c or c++ program (which I did write).

I tried googling but didn't get a proper answer.
Please check the image for more information

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA5BM.png

Comment: Show your code. But you're probably asking for scanf.

Comment: It's not my program. It's an .exe file that downloaded from the internet. It runs in coomand line and I want to provide input to it using a c or c++ program.

Comment: Have a look at pipes `|` and redirections `>`

Comment: how to redirect a the output from c to  a .exe application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code from this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles

Basically, you already have *child* (y-cruncher exe file) and you need to copy the code of *redirector* (your c file). Don't forget to change you exe name:

```
CreateProcess(NULL,"D:\\nerd_stuff\\project\\y-cruncher_v0.7.7.9501\\y-cruncher.exe",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi)
```

And set proper buffer size here:

```
if(!ReadConsole(hStdIn,read_buff,1,&nBytesRead,NULL))
            DisplayError("ReadConsole");
```

Should be:

```
if(!ReadConsole(hStdIn,read_buff,sizeof(read_buff),&nBytesRead,NULL))
            DisplayError("ReadConsole");
```

All these means, that you will be able to work as though you are "directly" working with y-cruncher. You will be able to process its output (whatever logic you wish to insert) and generate appropriate input in your code.